# Terraform Enterprise Race Condition?

Tags: azure, terraform

Running a terraform template locally using `terraform apply` works fine.  When I run it from terraform enterprise, however, I get different results.

First result was this (somewhat cleansed):

```
Error: Error retrieving Log Profile "..": insights.LogProfilesClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="Log profile 'swcdevmarsavlogprofile' under scope '/subscriptions/...' doesn't exist."
  on modules/.., in resource "azurerm_monitor_log_profile" "..":
 127: resource "azurerm_monitor_log_profile" ".." {
```

I figured it might be the service principle I was using which is different than what I am doing locally (just using az login).  However, the issue came up on a request to get the object....

Next time, I got a different error:

```
Error: Error Creating/Updating Subnet ".." (Virtual Network ".." / Resource Group ".."): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="AnotherOperationInProgress" Message="Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress. To retrieve status of the operation use uri: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/../providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/eastus/operations/..?api-version=2019-06-01." Details=[]
  on modules/../main.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "..":
  38: resource "azurerm_subnet" "workspace" {
```

This time, it fails on a `AnotherOperationInProgress` so this sure feels like a race condition to me.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share your terraform script?

Comment: My current theory is that I have an `azurerm_template_deployment`, and it had no dependencies defined (`depends_on`).  As such, I think what was happening was it saw that the template had no dependencies, and kicked off a thread for it.  This would explain why I got difference errors or successes at random. Added depends_on and testing.